# Given a spherical triangle ABC and a point P, find (u, v) for slerping

Tags: spherical-geometry

Hmm. Where am I going wrong? Firstly, I apologise, I'm only a programmer, and skinny also, not a maths bod.

Everything is on the unit sphere

I have a spherical equilateral triangle ABC and a 2D co-ordinate (u, v). I construct P using slerp:

D = slerp(A, B, u)
E = slerp(C, B, u)
P = slerp(D, E, v)

Now, given the point P and the triangle ABC, find (u, v). So, from the construction above, it should be really straightforward:

F = normalise(cross(C, A)) : the plane of the great circle defined by A and C
G = normalise(cross(B, P)) : the plane of the great circle defined by P and B
H = cross(F, G) : the intersections of the great circles AC and PB

v = Angle(AOH) / Angle(AOC)

This works. However...

I = normalise(cross(cross(G, P), P)) : the plane of the great circle defined by D and E?
J = normalise(Cross(B, A)) : plane of the great circle defined by A and B
K = Cross(I, J) : intersection of the great circles DE and AB

u = Angle(AOK) / Angle(AOB)

I cannot see where I'm going wrong here. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry, but what made you think that implying that the people you are asking to help you are fat would be a good introduction to your question?

Comment: $I$ is not the normal to the plane of $D$ and $E$, except in the special case where $P$ is the midpoint. $I$ is normal to $G$, so it lies on the great circle of $B$ and $P$, and is normal to $P$. The great circle it is normal to will be perpendicular to $\overset \frown {BP}$ at $P$. But $\overset \frown {DE}$ is not usually perpendicular to $\overset \frown {BP}$, so it will not be the great circle of $D$ and $E$.